# VB.NET "For each" versus ".GetUpperBound(0)"

Tags: vb.net, string, vector, foreach

I would like to know what is preferred...

```
    Dim sLines() As String = s.Split(NewLine)
```

For each:

```
    For Each sLines_item As String In sLines
```

.GetUpperBound:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To sLines.GetUpperBound(0)
```

I have no idea why the "For Each" was introduced for such cases. Until now I have only used .GetUpperBound, and I don't see any PRO for the "For Each".

Thank you

ps: When I use ."GetUpperBound(0)", I do know that I am iterating over the vector. 
The "For Each" in contrast sounds like "I don't care in which order the vector is given to me". But that is just personal gusto, I guess.

Comment: for each is a short cut to loop through each of an elements in an array no matter what the size of the array. So if you array changes dynamically and you have no clue what the length is the for each will take of it for you.

Comment: For Each doesn't care if the array is 0 based or 1 based, your For Next would need to take that into account.

Comment: @ExcelledProducts Can you give me an example for a situation where the length is unknown?

Comment: here is an article i found that links to three other articles over time. basically, i think it used to matter, but doesn't anymore. i like how easy it is to read a foreach vs a for, but that is personal preference. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/531893/For-Vs-Foreach-Benchmark

Comment: Why are you even considering `GetUpperBound()`  when `Array.Length` is there?

Comment: The length of an array is unknown mainly in an array list. You could have a loop that continuously adds data the the list based on a database that is ever changing.

Comment: `For Each` can iterate over many different types of objects, not just arrays, and many of these objects may expose no means for you to determine the length. Just for consistency, then, I'd normally use `For Each` with an array. But I feel the question is OT since it's just going to solicit opinions.

Comment: @dotNET I used the upgrader that was present in VS2005 or so, and it converted my VB6-UBound(SomeStringVec) to SomeStringVec.GetUpperBound(0). Is GetUpperBound(0) outdated?

Comment: The only advantage of `GetUpperBound()` works for multi-dimensional arrays, where `Length` doesn't work. However, even that usage is outdated since there is `Array.GetLength()` available. Looks like your upgrader needs an upgrade. :)

Comment: one other advantage is that For Each declares a variable and its type in one line, where a `For i As Int32` can require another var if you extract the contents to something (`var = myArray(i)`) to use or evaluate.  For Each is more for Lists and ArrayLists, BTW the 1980s called and want their arrays back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Do not use `GetUpperBound()`. The only advantage of `GetUpperBound()` is that it works for multi-dimensional arrays, where `Length` doesn't work. However, even that usage is outdated since there is `Array.GetLength()` available that takes the `dimension` parameter. For all other uses, `For i = 0 to Array.Length - 1` is better and probably the fastest option.

Comment: In VB.NET the "to" in "for" loop is inclusive. You will go out of the range if you use `For i = 0 to Array.Length` https://dotnetfiddle.net/GpKeot

Comment: `For i = 0 to Comments.Length - 1 : Console.WriteLine("Thanks") : Next` :)

Answer (score 0):

It's largely a personal preference.

If you need to alter the elements of the array, you should use `For i ...` because changing `sLines_item` will not affect the corresponding array element.

If you need to delete elements of the array, you can iterate `For i = ubound(sLines) to 0 step -1` (or the equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

You should always use `For Each` on `IEnumerable` types unless you have no other choice.

### Long answer

Contrary to the popular understanding, `For Each` is **not** a syntactic sugar on top of `For Next`. It will not necessarily iterate over every element of its source. It is a syntactic sugar on top of `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`. `For Each` will first get an enumerator to its source then loop until it cannot enumerate further. Basically, it will be replaced by the following code. Keep in mind that this is an oversimplification.

```
' Ask the source for a way to enumerate its content in a forward only manner.
Dim enumerator As IEnumerator = sLines.GetEnumerator()
' Loop until there is no more element in front of us.
While enumerator.Next() Then
    ' Invoke back the content of the for each block by passing
    ' the currently enumerated element.
    forEachContent.Invoke(enumerator.Current)
End While
```

The major difference between this and a classical `For Next` loop is that it does not depend on any length. This fixes two limitations in modern .NET languages. The first one has to do with the `Count` method. `IEnumerable` provides a `Count` method, but the implementation might not be able to keep track of the actual amount of elements it stores. Because of this, calling `IEnumerable.Count` might cause the source to be iterated over to actually count the amount of element it contains. Moreover, doing this as the end value for traditional `For Next` loop will cause this process to be done for every element in the loop. This is very slow. Here is an illustration of this process:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To source.Count()  ' This here will cause Count to be
                                        ' evaluated for every element in source.
    DoSomething(source(i))
Next
```

The use of `For Each` fixes this by never requesting the length of the source.

The second limitation it fixes is the lack of a concept for arrays with infinite amount of elements. An example of such cases would be an array containing every digit of PI where each digit is only calculated when you request them. This is where LINQ makes its entrance and really shines because it enables you to write the following code:

```
Dim piWith10DigitPrecision = From d In InfinitePiSource
                             Take 10
Dim piWith250DigitPrecision = From d In InfinitePiSource
                              Take 250
Dim infite2PiSource = From d In InfinitePiSource
                      Select d * 2
```

Now, in an infinite source, you cannot depend on a length to iterate over all of its elements. It has an infinite length thus making a traditional `For Next` loop an infinite loop. This does not change anything for the first two examples I have given with pi because we explicitly provides the amount of elements we want, but it does for the third one. When would you stop iterating? `For Each`, when combined with `Yield` (used by the `Take` operator), makes sure that you never iterate until you actually requests a specific value.

You might have already figured it out by now but these two things means that `For Each` effectively have no concept of bounds because it simply does not require them. The only use for `GetLowerBound` and `GetUpperBound` are for non-zero-indexed arrays. For instance, you might have an array that indexes values from 1 instead of zero. Even then, you only need `GetLowerBound` and `Length`. Obviously, this is only if the position of the element in the source actually matters. If it does not, you can still use `For Each` to iterate over all elements as it is bound agnostic.

Also, as already mentioned, `GetLength` should be used for zero-indexed multi-dimensional arrays, again, only if the position of the element matters and not just the element itself.